# What happens if the Upper and Lower Bounds of an Algorithm are the SAME?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, lower-bound, upperbound

Just what the question asks. Its a question for my midterm tomorrow and I cant seem to find the answer anywhere online or in my textbook. Thanks for the Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the algorithm's complexity only depend on the size of the input data, not its content.

Comment: Thank You!! I've been trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: I am only answering what I think, I can't be sure that it is THE answer you need. I recommend you to double check with your peers.

Comment: @Vincent: Consider an algorithm for finding the average of an array of integers. For an array of n items, that's always going to take the same time regardless of the contents of the array. So the upper and lower bounds are the same. Contrast that will sequential search, which could take 1 iteration (the item is in the first position), or could take n iterations (the item is at the end of the array). Or comparison sorting, which is very dependent on the order of items.

Comment: Thanks Jim,to validate the answer.